# How to setup a script to disable a validator based on a DDL input

Tags: jquery, asp.net

The code below disables a validator based on a radiobuttonlist input. I would like to do the same thing, but with a dropdownlist instead. Thanks.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#<%=RadioButtonList8.ClientID%>").click(function () {
        var rbvalue = $("input[name='<%=RadioButtonList8.UniqueID%>']:radio:checked").val();
        if (rbvalue == "Yes") {
            ValidatorEnable(document.getElementById('<%=Validator9.ClientID%>'), false);
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#<%=YourDDLID.ClientID%>").change(function() {
        var ddlvalue = $("#<%=YourDDLID.ClientID%>").val();
        if (ddlvalue == "Check your DDL value here") {
            ValidatorEnable(document.getElementById('<%=Validator9.ClientID%>'), false);
        }
    });
});
</script>
```